# sails-postgres error: invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: postgresql, sails.js

I'm building an application in sails.js with postgresql database. The model is:

```
attributes: {
name: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},
username: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true
},
password: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},
rating: {
  type: 'integer'
},
toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to create a new user, I get an error as follows:

> sails-postgres error: invalid input syntax for type json.

How can I solve this problem?